# How to Prevent Search Engine Index only on product page?

Tags: php, opencart, search-engine

I want all the product pages to be no index. They should not be indexed by google or any search engine. I only want to rank the category pages, site information etc.

Comment: Well you need to use `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`on the pages that are not allowed to be indexed..

Comment: @Naruto on a dynamic system i cant use this option becasue my product pages are dynamic. i can solve my problem with robots.text code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create robots.txt in root of site and code next

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /products/*
```

Please read documentation for robots.txt,  * - means any symbols.

You can try to use such generator
http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/generator/

Or better hire professional.

Comment: 1) The file has to be called `robots.txt`, not `robot.txt`. 2) No need for the `*` after `/products/`, because in `Disallow` it’s always the *beginning* of the URL path anyway. 3) robots.txt prevents crawling, not necessarily indexing.